# can isopropyl alcohol dissolve powder coat?

Tags: wood, outdoor, furniture, metal

I have new outdoor furniture that is metal frame & wooden body. The metal frame is painted black, using powder coat I think. I was applying wood protector on the wood parts, and it stained the metal frame. I couldn't clean it with water, so I tried isopropyl alcohol. It removed the wood protector stains very easily, but: On two pieces it worked fine, but on the third one I started picking up some black stain, and now I'm worried that I started rubbing off the paint.

Is it possible that I accidentally removed the paint, or is it just some other stain that I picked up? The part is still black underneath, but I definitely removed a layer of something, so maybe it was painted twice, and I removed one layer?

Can isopropyl alcohol act as a solvent for the paint?

In the photo you can see how it looks above the bottom corner of the frame. There are definitely two layers of something, the light reflection is different. [image: damaged frame]

Comment: I do not think that IPA will affect any powder coat or many paints the finish may have had other solvents that affected the coating and you are wiping this and some of the coating off.

Comment: Thanks Ed! Do you mean that something from the wood protector had something that affected the paint?

Comment: That would be my guess some have other solvents like toluene that is a stronger chemical that evaporates quickly.